# c# Extract data from mysql in json format

Tags: c#, mysql, json

I'm developing an application in windows form,I have json data in my mysql database ,column = data
'{"money":0,"goal":0,"advantage":0}'
I'm trying to pull this data into tags in the form,label1.text="money";label2.text="goal";label3.text="advantage";
I could not find enough resources like this and I am inexperienced in this regard.
I uploaded the Json nouget package to my form.
output ='{"money":0,"goal":0,"advantage":0}'
How can I get json data as I want.
Thanks for your help.

```
MySqlConnection baglan = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=json;user=root;Pwd=;");
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        baglan.Open();
       MySqlCommand kom = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM player_accounts", baglan);
        int count = Convert.ToInt32(kom.ExecuteScalar());
        if (count != 0)
        {

            MySqlDataReader oku = kom.ExecuteReader();
            while (oku.Read())
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(oku["data"].ToString());

            }
            baglan.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON data is always the same, the 1st thing I would create is a model class to house the data in C# land.

So, something like this::

```
public class Data
{
    public decimal money { get; set; }
    public int goal { get; set; }
    public int advantage { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your function, I would convert the JSON data to this new object and return from the function.  For this you will need to go to nuget and install [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Now you can write something like this:

```
var dbData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(oku["data"]);
```

instead of your line:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(oku["data"].ToString());
```

The function would look something like this:

```
private List<Data> GetDatabaseData()
{
    var resultList = new List<Data>();

    MySqlConnection baglan = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=json;user=root;Pwd=;");
    baglan.Open();
    MySqlCommand kom = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM player_accounts", baglan);
    int count = Convert.ToInt32(kom.ExecuteScalar());
    if (count != 0)
    {
        MySqlDataReader oku = kom.ExecuteReader();
        while (oku.Read())
        {
            var data JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(ku["data"].ToString());
            resultList.Add(data);
        }
        baglan.Close();
    }

    return resultList;
}
```

You can then use the function like this:

```
var dataList = GetDatabaseData();
foreach( var item in dataList )
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(item.money);
}
```